# error on one of my methods of my tictactoe game

Tags: java

I keep getting the following error.

The user can only enter a number from 1 to 9. And this is what my error shows:

> hint: does getemptyspot return valid entered spot even with initial zero entry:
>   hint: does getemptyspot return valid entered spot even with initial 10 entry.

Also, if the board is full, my code should return `-1`. And if the spot is already taken, my code should return `"That number is not available. Choose another from the numbered spots"`

My code is as follows:

```
public int getEmptySpot()
{
    System.out.print("Choose a number where you want your marker to go");
    int spot = in.nextInt();
    if(b.isAvailable(spot)) 
    {
        return spot;
    }
    if(spot == 0 || spot > 10)
    {
        System.out.println("That number is not available. Choose another from   the numbered spots");
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You probably want to check if `spot` is in range (1-9) before you check if it is available.And then, if its not in range, return `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may you post the detail of `isAvailable()`?
it looks like the code cannot reach the 2nd `if()` sub.
why use the different styles of the `if()`?
try like this:

```
if(spot >0 && spot <10){
    return spot;
}else{
}
```